# Why the preparedStatement is not working in jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have created a table called user in mysql. Then I create a simple j frame with having a text field and a button. The button will add the name in the DB after pressing the button. But is showing an error at **insertData.InsertData$2.actionPerformed(InsertData.java:86)** means there are some issue with prepared statement. I have tried without prepared statement but problem is not solved.
Most important my table having 4 columns called (name, id, Email,Phone)

```
package insertData;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class InsertData {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    Connection connection;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InsertData window = new InsertData();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public InsertData() {
        initialize();
        createConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    
    
    public void createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//load driver    
            java.sql.Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shykat_db","root","root");    //Establish connection
            System.out.println("sucess");
                        
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
        
    
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 25, 174, 44);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit\r\n");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                try {
                    
                    String name=textField.getText();    
                    String drop="insert into user values(?) ";
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps= ((java.sql.Connection) connection).prepareStatement(drop);
                    System.out.println(ps);
                    ps.setString(1, name);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    //ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    //System.out.println(rs);
                    
                    //java.sql.Statement stm=((java.sql.Connection) connection).createStatement();
                    //String drop="insert into user values(' "+name+" ')";  

                    //stm.execute(drop);
                    //stm.close();
                    //int count=ps.executeUpdate();
                    //System.out.println(count+"-----Data updated");
                    
                    ps.close();
                    
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(313, 26, 89, 44);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
}
```

[image: This is the screenshot of my table and its collumn]

Comment: Showing an error such as what?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert into only some columns of a multi column table, you must declare which columns you want to insert into after the table name

```
INSERT INTO t(column,list,goes,here)
VALUES(samenumber,ofvalues,asthere,arecolumns)
```

Your user table has at least 4 columns, you cannot say `insert into user values(?)` because your database will not be prepared to guess which column the value should go in. Try `insert into user(name) values(?)`